# what is maximum value of $\frac{\sin(n\theta)}{\theta}$?

Tags: calculus

I differentiated it with respect to theta and equated the equation to zero than the result comes out to be   $\tan n\theta={n\theta}$. How to proceed further?

Comment: Please show your work so that we can see how you arrived at the equation $\tan\theta = \theta$.

Comment: What happened to $\;n\;$ in your differentiation?

Comment: Also, please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: differentiate the above equation sin(n*theta)/theta wrt to theta and equate to zero you will get tan(theta)=theta

Comment: @AeronMo No, you certainly won't: $\;n\;$ in the trigonometric functions' argument does **not** vanish!

Comment: can you please explain further the fault was in writing incorrect sentence

Comment: @AeronMo After your editing, the derivative *still* is wrong. You need to be pretty careful with this.

Comment: @AeronMo It **still** is wrong...Why won't you read one of the answers below??

Comment: yes i am naive to latex difficulty in writing this language that's why writing wrong

Comment: @AeronMo It is not LaTeX  related as you correctly wrote your question's title: it is only a matter of writing $\;\tan \color{red}n\theta\;$ instead of the incorrect $\;\tan\theta\;$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\left(\frac{\sin n\theta}{\theta}\right)'=\frac{n\theta\cos n\theta-\sin n\theta}{\theta^2}$$
and the above derivative vanishes if
$$n\theta\cos n\theta-\sin n\theta=0.$$

We can easily see that $\theta=0$ is a solution for each integer $n$.
There are two things to do now :

1. Check that $\frac{\sin n\theta}{\theta}$ exist when $\theta\rightarrow0$ ;
2. Check that in $\theta=0$ the global maximum of the function is attained.

Comment: I can't understand why you edited your correct thrid line and wrote that incorrect one...

Comment: yes the answer comes out to be n

Comment: Timbuc : it is because I devided by $\cos n\theta$, which can be zero for some $\theta$. The "iff" was just a typo, I fixed it, thank you!

Comment: Aeron Mo : it is indeed the correct answer, try to properly show it.

Comment: @Nicolas If you write $\;\tan x\;$ I think it is a fairly simple and widely accepted assumption that $\;x\neq\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi}2\;$ , but even then: your third line must be equalled to zero, mustn't it?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry! You're right! As for writing $\tan n\theta$, I didn't want to considerate all the different cases because the zero solution was the good one and it can be easily read in the third line.

Comment: by applying L'Hôpital's rule we can find limit $ \theta \rightarrow $  0 this solu

Answer (score 0):

$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right]=\dfrac{f'(x)\times g(x)-g'(x)\times f(x)}{\left[g(x)\right]^2}$$
$$\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\left[\dfrac{\sin(n\theta)}{\theta}\right]=\dfrac{n\cos(n\theta)\times\theta-1\times\sin(n\theta)}{\theta^2}=\dfrac{n\theta\cos(n\theta)-\sin(n\theta)}{\theta^2}$$